# Display map with emulator android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

``Hi everybody! I try to display a map which is already in my sdcard in emulator but when I run my program, it shows me error: sorry proccess has stopped unexpectedly.
Here is my logs:

```
   10-05 08:12:12.213: W/dalvikvm(1913): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/ossmap/MainActivity; (975)
10-05 08:12:12.213: W/dalvikvm(1913): Link of class 'Lcom/google/ossmap/MainActivity;' failed
10-05 08:12:12.234: D/AndroidRuntime(1913): Shutting down VM
10-05 08:12:12.234: W/dalvikvm(1913): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.google.ossmap/com.google.ossmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ossmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.google.ossmap-2.apk
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ossmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.google.ossmap-2.apk
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
10-05 08:12:12.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1913):     ... 11 more
10-05 08:17:12.404: I/Process(1913): Sending signal. PID: 1913 SIG: 9
```

My MainActivity:

```
     package com.google.ossmap;

import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;

//import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
//        mapView.setMapFile("/sdcard/osm.map");
//        setContentView(mapView); 

        mapView.setMapFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/osm.map");
        setContentView(mapView); 

    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.ossmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ossmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.google.ossmap-2.apk
```

try to change package name (not wise to use com.google.*) or add full path to class to manifest

```
android:name="com.google.ossmap.MainActivity"
```

Comment: Thanks! I have already done as you said but I have always the same problem! Is it a problem caused by my code or ..?